# Parts of objects that were copy-pasted in Blender are broken when Instantiated in unity but NOT when dragged into editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

[Correct Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSt53.png)

[Broken Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEBXO.png)

The topmost arrow in the image was dragged into the game window, and seems to render fine. The bottom arrow, however, is the same model - which was Instantiated from a static method using:

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("Arrow", typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer));
```

For some reason this breaks some objects, while dragging doesn't. The missing part of the arrow is one that copy pasted into Blender. I made the head from a cube, copied, it then linked the objects and drew the shaft between them. I've noticed a lot of issues in Blender-Unity importing with objects like this. The arrowhead is definitely missing, not invisible. When I first tried this I briefly saw it stretched across the terrain. Any ideas why? I have applied the Delta scale to the object and exported using FBX All.

Things I tried:

Backface culling is enabled. Replacing parts of that head doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Enable Backface Culling in Blender -> does it still look correct in Blender? ;) => Looks like your normals are inverted.

Comment: That image is with backface culling enabled. I tried both with and without, based on other answers.

Comment: _"`new GameObject(...)`"_ - that's not how you instantiate a `GameObject`.  Use `Instantiate()` instead. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: I'm aware of instantiate. "new GameObject(...)" seems to work better in editor scripts. However I my revisit the code and use it instead to see if it fixes a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that, by merging two objects, I created an object with two material slots - only one of which was being filled. The trick is to open the object in the Blender hierarchy and unlink one of the materials that is linked to it.

[Rightclick and use unlink on one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0IIb.png)